# Root/Solution confusion

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, learning

Suppose I have the equation $x-a=0$.
So, $x-a=0\Rightarrow x=a$. The unique solution is (or root) $a$ (by definition a solution is the value for the unknown that make the equation true, $a-a=0$ ).
Since $x=a$ shouldn't x(the unknown) considered a solution?

Sorry if the question isn't clear but i have this stupid doubt.

Comment: The problem is not just that the question is unclear, but that it isn't even a question, Could you please clean it up, add in the missing word or words, and actually say what it is that you asking?

Comment: If $x$ is the unknown in an equation, then a solution of the equation isa value which, when substituted for the variable $x$, makes the equation true. By this definition, $x$ fails to be a solution for two reasons. First, it isn't a value but a variable. Second, when you substitute $x$ for $x$, the equation remains $x-a=0$, which is not true (nor is it false, because $x$ is still a variable with no chosen value).

Comment: Your doubt is not stupid but you show an open window to see after what is true. If $x$ were a solution  it would no longer be called unknown.

Answer (score 4):

In the equation $x = a$, the $x$ is a variable rather than a number. The way you want to think about it is: What can I put in the brackets so this equation is true?
$$[\ ] = a$$

The "$x$" doesn't exist on its own as a number, it's like having brackets that say "put some numbers in me!"

If you put $a$ in the equation, then you get $a = a$, which is true. If you put somthing which isn't $a$ in the equation, it's false. However, $x$ is not a solution because it is just a placeholder that represents "where you plug numbers into your equation".

However, a bit of care needs to be taken: It is correct to say "$x$ is the solution if $x = a$". In this case $x$ is no longer a variable, but it's literally the value of $a$.

**EDIT**

The part above was a bit ambiguous, I've tried to clarify it a bit.
It depends on context. The "equation" $x = a$ is equivalent to the "function" $f(x) = x-a$, where a "root" of the equation is a "zero" of the function. However, if you have some number $a$ and define $x$ to be equal to $a$, usually denoted $x := a$ then it's no longer a function or an equation - $x$ is no longer a variable, it's the same object as $a$. Thus $x = a$ can have different meanings - either $x$ is a variable and $x=a$ is an equation, or $x$ is a constant, and $x=a$ is a definition.

Comment: you say: however, a bit of care needs to be taken: It is correct to say "x is the solution if x=a". In this case x is no longer a variable, but it's literally the value of a. When you say "...if x=a." don't I state this when I write the equation in the first place?

Comment: I've tried to clarify it, hopefully it makes more sense.

Comment: now is all clear.